# Glitchy XRDP Output on Raspberry Pi 4b Running Ubuntu

Tags: raspberrypi, remote, xrdp

I recently reformatted my Raspberry Pi 4b microSD card to use Ubuntu since I like it better than Raspbian. Usually I can resolve something like this, but the problem has taken a good chunk of time from my day. Does anyone have any possible solutions to resolve this glitchy output from XRDP? I am using the Windows 10 Remote Desktop Connection software to connect to it.

[image]

Comment: Since it works on my Raspi 4, it might be windows problem?

Comment: Providing details of your Ubuntu system may help; what Ubuntu system have you installed? and what release?

Comment: I’m running the latest Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS. I’ve run a sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade and everything is up to date.